# wildcard routing issue on Apache server deployment

Tags: angular-routing

ill develop my project in angular 15 and every thing working perfectly but after build and deployed on apache2 server the wildcard routing 404 error page is not working and behalf of that server default 404 error page is displayed how can we solve this problem?

change in .htaccess file

Comment: Your question needs a bit more detail. It would be helpful to provide the config you are currently using for Apache2. Also provide an example URL that is working and one that is not (wildcard example) using Apache2.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. To make things run more smoothly, please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/help) of how SO works and especially [How To Ask Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then please edit your question with more detail so others could help you out.